# Is there any way I can restrict the access to Site Pages in Communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages, communication-site

I have a requirement to give option to control permission for users to post content, For eg :In the announcement section only Marketing & IT department should have access to publish content. In the HR section, only the HR department should have access to publish content. How can I handle this, as all the news post goes o Site Pages library. Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If different sections are in different pages, you can create unique permission on pages to control access from end users. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

Comment: This is by setting unique permission for each pages in Site Pages library, right?

Comment: @Reshma Yes, apply unique permission settings according  to your requirement.